# How to run Java Telegram Bot

Tags: java, maven, telegram-bot

I have been created a menu for my telegram bot using java maven in netbeans ide. but when i hit run to test it locally from my pc and try it online, it only build my project again.

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>TelBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>6.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.telbot.TelBot</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
</project>
```

my main.java

```
package com.mycompany.telbot;

import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new Bot());
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

my bot.java

```
package com.mycompany.telbot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.BreakNode;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.ReplyKeyboardMarkup;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.KeyboardButton;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.KeyboardRow;

public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot{
    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "-----------";
    }
    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "--------------------------------------------";
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if(update.getMessage().getText().equals("/start")){
            MainMenu();
        }
    }
    
    public void MainMenu(){
        ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
        replyKeyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
        replyKeyboardMarkup.setSelective(true);
        List<KeyboardRow> keyboardRowList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        KeyboardRow keyboardRow1 = new KeyboardRow();
        KeyboardButton keyboardButton1 = new KeyboardButton();
        keyboardButton1.setText("Some Text");
        keyboardRow1.add(keyboardButton1);
        
        KeyboardRow keyboardRow2 = new KeyboardRow();
        KeyboardButton keyboardButton2 = new KeyboardButton();
        keyboardButton2.setText("Some Text");
        keyboardRow2.add(keyboardButton2);
        KeyboardButton keyboardButton3 = new KeyboardButton();
        keyboardButton3.setText("Some Text");
        keyboardRow2.add(keyboardButton3);
        KeyboardButton keyboardButton4 = new KeyboardButton();
        keyboardButton4.setText("Some Text");
        keyboardRow2.add(keyboardButton4);
        
        KeyboardRow keyboardRow3 = new KeyboardRow();
        KeyboardButton keyboardButton5 = new KeyboardButton();
        keyboardButton5.setText("Some Text");
        keyboardRow3.add(keyboardButton5);
        
        KeyboardRow keyboardRow4 = new KeyboardRow();
        KeyboardButton keyboardButton6 = new KeyboardButton();
        keyboardButton6.setText("Some Text");
        keyboardRow4.add(keyboardButton6);
        KeyboardButton keyboardButton7 = new KeyboardButton();
        keyboardButton7.setText("Some Text");
        keyboardRow4.add(keyboardButton7);
        KeyboardButton keyboardButton8 = new KeyboardButton();
        keyboardButton8.setText("Some Text");
        keyboardRow4.add(keyboardButton8);
        
        keyboardRowList.add(keyboardRow1);
        keyboardRowList.add(keyboardRow2);
        keyboardRowList.add(keyboardRow3);
        keyboardRowList.add(keyboardRow4);
        replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboardRowList);
    }
}
```

I checked my bot username and api several times, and they are correct.
I tried to run the compiled project (.jar file) using cmd, but didn't worked.
I checked my network speed, and it's good.
By the way telegram is filtered in my country so I'm using proxy & VPN.

Comment: "but didn't worked" meaning what, exactly? Did it throw an exception? Did it behave differently than what you expected? What happened?

Comment: I want to test my bot, I mean to use my pc as locall server (run the project).
but I can not. I don't know what is the problem.
I'm new to maven projects.